# apache/nginx html file size limit

Tags: apache-2.2, configuration, nginx

When serving/sending HTML files to a users browser, where can I reconfigure this size limit?

I want to send an extremely large html files to users via apache and nginx.

Files are being truncated in apache/nginx, what setting determines the file size?

Comment: At what size are they being truncated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've managed to download a 1GB HTML file from nginx 0.8.28 without any problems. Are you using gzip compression? You may need to set appropriate gzip_buffers size or even disable it at all, if the HTML files are so big.

Comment: 1GB is not a large file.  A file would need to be at least 2GB to hit any 32bit file size issues.

Comment: @Justin - 1GB is a *huge* text file, though

Answer (score 9):

in nginx, add the following line to your nginx.conf file:

```
client_max_body_size 2G;
```

for a 2gb file limit.

Larger than that, and you might run into other issues (ie, like your local filesystem having problems with big files, memory spikes for processing, etc).

Check [this post](http://www.jedi.be/blog/2009/04/10/rails-and-large-large-file-uploads-looking-at-the-alternatives/) for further comparisons and problems with large files.